# Click event requires validation before click - how to cancel it? Webforms

Tags: c#, webforms

I would like to cancel validation (the required attribute in the input field) with a specific button (id="btn").

front-end - aspx file:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" runat="server" required>
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btn" Text="Click" OnClick="foo" CausesValidation="false"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btn2" Text="Click" OnClick="bar"/>
```

Code-behind:

```
        protected void foo(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
        protected void bar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
        }
```

I added the attribute CausesValidation and it doesn't work for me.

Thanks.

Comment: where is the validation happening?

Comment: required attribute inside the input field.

Comment: try adding client-side onclick method and add removeAttr('required') to the required element in it.

Answer (score 1):

If set the `CausesValidation` not working for you then you can use validation group property for `btn2` button

for E.g :

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" runat="server" ValidationGroup="group1"
 required  >
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btn" Text="Click" OnClick="foo" />
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btn2" Text="Click"  ValidationGroup="group1" OnClick="bar"/>
```

Comment: Thanks.
but It doesn't work for me.
still requires validation for the input field.